Why is vim.fs.joinpath() missing from neovim 0.9.5 on macOS?
The online documentation mentions vim.fs.joinpath() but I can't find that on my local Neovim with :help vim.fs.joinpath, it's not on :help lua at all. And :lua print(vim.fs.joinpath) says it's nil.
I can see the function vim.fs.joinpath was added on may 2023 PR #23685 and it's still there on github as of 2024-04-09:
So how come vim.fs.joinpath() is not included in the build for Neovim 0.9.5 (tried with the official Neovim release and using homebrew)?

Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the answers using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons? It allow the question to rest :-)

The online documentation is the documentation of the trunk (the unstable version). It include the documentation of vim.fs.joinpath
At the date of today (9th of April 2024):

The 0.9.5 is the stable version.
The 0.10 is the unstable version.

I believe this is what explains the difference between the two.
Remark: if you look at the source of the branch for the runtime/lua/vim/fs.lua you'll see that the joinpath function is not present yet. Although the patch of 20th of May 2023 is before the release of Dec 2023 the patch hasn't been merge into the stable branch.

I just built  neovim from source both master 0.10.0 and stable 0.9.5 and effectively 0.10.0 has vim.fn.joinpath, but I'm confused since 0.9.5 was released on December 2023 and the vim.fs.joinpath was added  May 2023.  I guess, since 0.9.0 was created on April 2023 they don't add anythin "new" to 0.9.x and they keep all the new stuff parked until 0.10.x. I didn't expect to be delayed more than a year.

nvim 0.10.0 is planned for 2023-04-30 https://github.com/neovim/neovim/milestone/36 so I guess I won't have to wait much longer.

Thanks for the feedback. Looking at the 0.9 branch history I observed the same :-) Good to know that the 0.10 version will be released soon :-)

Seems that 0.10.0 was released on 2024-05-16 and it's not available in package manager like homebrew
